# Why the image URL generated by S3 is corrupted (0 bytes) when it is uploaded in sub folders using Flask python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-s3, boto3

I have to upload multiple images to subfolders of S3 bucket but once the images are attached the image object URL is either 0KB or 1KB in size and when I open it, it says file is corrupted.

Python code:

```
    from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename 
    url_attach = []
    image_file = request.files.getlist('files')
    for item in image_file:
        filename = secure_filename(item.filename)
        url = upload2s3(item, filename)
        url_attach.append(url)
```

upload function:

```
def upload2s3(img_content, key_name):
    try:
        file_name = AWS_BUCKET_SUBFOLDER + "/" + str(key_name)
        s3_conn = boto3.client(
            "s3",
            aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY,
        )
        x = s3_conn.put_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Body=img_content, Key=file_name)
        url = create_url(BUCKET_NAME, file_name )
        return url
    except Exception as ex:
        return {"status": False, "message": ex}
```

url function:

```
def create_url(bucket, object):

    client = boto3.client(
        "s3", aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY
    )

    return client.generate_presigned_url(
        "get_object", Params={"Bucket": bucket, "Key": object}
    )
```

cofig:

```
BUCKET_NAME:test_dir
AWS_BUCKET_SUBFOLDER:test
```

sample url: `https://test_dir.s3.amazonaws.com/test/XYZ.png?AWSAccessKeyId=###########&Signature=##############&Expires=#########`

error: corrupted image (0 bytes). The image is uploaded in correct format when I don't put it in bucket subfolders and directly upload to bucket.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to determine from the code available, but it seems to me that before you say `Body = img_content` you need to first open the `img_content` variable because it looks like the `img_content` variable is a  filename. Try:

```
with open(img_content, 'r') as img_body:
    x = s3_conn.put_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Body=img_body, Key=file_name)
```